# Making Python 3.3.3 scripts executable?

Tags: python, executable, py2exe

I've googled and googled, and everything I've seen has directed me to py2exe. I've looked at it and downloaded the latest version of it, but it says I have to have Python 2.6 to use it! Does this mean I have to use Python 2.6 rather than 3.3.3, or is there an alternative to py2exe?

Edit: Thanks! I can now use cxFreeze, but is there a way I can compile it further so I don't have to run it from a different folder? Or should I create a batch file calling the .exe from the command line and convert the batch file to an executable?

Answer (score 3):

The [latest version of py2exe (0.9.2)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0) support python 3 http://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/feature-requests/20/

Also you can try [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) it's like py2exe but cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

On most *nix systems it is sufficient to put `#!/usr/bin/python` as the first line of the main script and then `chmod +x /path/to/script.py`.

Comment: It's kind of obvious that OP is using Windows

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` is usually Python 2.x. `/usr/bin/python3` or `/usr/bin/env python3` would be better.